# SQL SELECT Previous MMYY as varchar(4)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Dearest genius StackOverflow friends,

I'm in the need of creating a view that will always give me data in the WHERE clause for "Period" looking for the previous Month and Year (**MMYY**) in varchar(4) format.

Example:  Today is March 3rd, 2015, so what I need is for **Period** to be **0215**.

```
SELECT stuff
FROM   table
WHERE  period = '0215'
```

How do I automatically generate the '0215' in the view so I'm always seeing last months data?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's just a string. you can trivially use the built in-date functions to produce your month/year values and convert them to strings.

Comment: Did you try anything involving `CAST` and `DATEPART`?  A little `DATEADD`?  Some `RIGHT` for the leading zeroes?

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()), 101), 3, 6, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
;WITH PrevMonth AS (
   SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(date, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())), '-', ''), 6) AS YYYYMM
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(YYYYMM, 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(YYYYMM, 3, 2) AS MMYY 
FROM PrevMonth
```

The `CTE` yields the date of previous month in `YYYYMM` format. Using `SUBSTRING` the format is rearranged to produce the required output.

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ it's a lot easier to get the desired result using `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()), 'MMyy') AS MMYY
```

Comment: Why are you using a CTE?  That seems awfully convoluted, and `CONCAT` is also only SQL 2012+.  If you're using SQL Server 2008 or less, you can just do `WHERE  period = REPLACE(RIGHT(convert(varchar(8), dateadd(m, -1, GETDATE()), 3), 5), '/', '')`.   One line of code instead of five

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks for your valuable remarks. I didn't know of the usage of `CONVERT` that you mention. Hence, I use a `CTE` as  some sort of inline implementation of this function.

Answer (score 0):

you can get what you want using

TO_CHAR(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'MMYY')

of course you can replace sysdate with timestamp, if necessary.

Comment: Yes is Oracle. The alternative for SQL Server is DATEADD(mm, TestFrequency, TestDate)